# how do i know if a revision 247389 in branch RC-1 was merged into trunk

Tags: svn

I have a revision 247389, which was committed to RC-1 branch, but i am testing trunk, so how do i know if this particular revision WAS indeed merged to trunk, and how can i see the changes

i tried:

```
svn mergeinfo eligible --show-revs https://svn.a.b.c/repo/trunk https://svn.a.b.c/repo/branches/RC-1
```

but i get an error:

```
svn: 'https://svn.a.b.c/repo/branches/RC-1' is not a valid --show-revs value
```

i also dont want to do :

```
svn diff --old http://.../repo/branches/0.4.x --new http://.../repo/trunk/
```

as this gives me error:

```
not relative to base URLs
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just look at the mergeinfo on trunk, and that would tell you all the paths and revisions that it has received.

```
svn pg svn:mergeinfo http://.../repo/trunk/
```

To see if the changes are present in trunk, diff trunk at the revision where you committed the merge of the branch with the branch at revision 247389, and they should be identical.

So if you created revision 250000 when you merged that branch to trunk you would do something like this:

```
svn diff http://.../repo/trunk/@250000 http://.../repo/branches/0.4.x@247389 --summarize
```

You would likely want to be more specific on the URLs and drill down to the location of the changes that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got the syntax for the mergeinfo command wrong.

To get a list of commits to the branch, eligible for merge to trunk you should use the following command

```
svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible https://svn.a.b.c/repo/branches/RC-1 https://svn.a.b.c/repo/trunk
```

If you are unable to find r247389 in this list, it means that it has been merged to trunk.

To see what changes r247389 consist of, I would just look in the branch with the diff command.

```
svn diff -c 247389 https://svn.a.b.c/repo/branches/RC-1
```